# Create a table for following condition

Tags: sql, database, create-table, check-constraints

**condition for the problem to be solved:**

[image: This is the following condition to create the table]

The code i tried to do is

```
create table article ( 
    ArCode CHAR(5),
    ArName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
    Rate Number(8,2) , 
    Quantity NUMBER(4) CHECK (Quantity>0) DEFAULT 0 ,
    Class CHAR(1)
);
```

I couldn't solve the first condition and so i am getting right  parenthesis missing for final condition

Comment: This isnt MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would translate your requirement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE article ( 
    ArCode   CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(ArCode like 'A%'), 
    ArName   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    Rate     NUMERIC(8,2),
    Quantity NUMERIC(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK (Quantity >= 0),
    Class    CHAR(1) CHECK(Class in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
);
```

Changes to your original code:

- you want `NUMERIC` rather than `NUMBER`
- `ArCode` must be declared as `PRIMARY KEY`, and needs a check constraint to enfore the "Must begin with A" requirement
- the check constraint on `Quantity` should allow `0` value (that's the default!)
- `Class` needs a check constraint on the list of allowed values

Comment: what should i do inorder to begin the ArCode with character 'A'?